# RSpec unit testing parameters

Tags: rspec

I have the following code:

```
RSpec.describe OtsState do

  let(:campaign) { build(:campaign, from: Time.now+1.weeks, to: Time.now+2.weeks) }

  subject { campaign.deployment.ots_state }
  before { campaign.deployment.build_ots_state }

  describe "#set_target" do

    def check_ots_target(target,expected)
      ots_state = subject
      ots_state.set_target(target)

      expect(ots_state.ots_target).to eq(expected)
    end


    it 'should set target to 5 when 1 week period and set target to 5' do
      check_ots_target(5,5)
    end

    it 'should set target to 2 when 2 week period and set target to 1' do
      campaign.set(to: campaign.from+2.weeks)
      check_ots_target(1,2)
    end

    it 'should set target to 1 when 1 day period and set target to 7' do
      campaign.set(to: campaign.from+1.days)
      check_ots_target(7,1)
    end
  end

end
```

is there a way in RSpec to write it as a single test with 3 parameter sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RSpec matchers with a [fluent interface](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher-with-fluent-interface/):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_ots_target do |expected|
  match do |ots_state|
    ots_state.ots_target == expected
  end

  description do
    "have ots_target #{expected} when period is #{@period.inspect} and target is #{@target}"
  end

  chain :when_period_is do |period|
    @period = period
  end

  chain :and_target_is do |target|
    @target = target
  end
end
```

which allows something like this:

```
describe do
  let(:period) { 1.weeks }
  let(:target) { 5 }
  it { is_expected.to have_ots_target(5).when_period_is(period).and_target_is(target) }
end
```

but I prefer to just repeat the example and change the inputs:

```
describe "#set_target" do
  describe "when period is 2 weeks" do
    let(:period) { 2.weeks }
    describe "and target is 1" do
      it "returns 2" do
        expect(subject.set_target(1).to eq 2
       end
    end
  end
end
```

which is easier to write and easier to read.